# Times series dataframe to panel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert this times series shaped dataframe to a panel shaped dataframe. This is the head:

```
Código do Município,Código da Grande Região,Código UF,Nome da UF,Sigla da UF,MS/Jan2020,MS/Fev2020,MS/Mar2020,MS/Abr2020,MS/Mai2020,MS/Jun2020,MS/Jul2020,MS/Aug2020,MS/Set2020
110001,1,11,Rondônia,RO,-1188.0,-17586.389719238505,13315.370187988505,-17071.370004883036,-15917.5302734375,1424.3000390622788,32789.29981445335,12751.559692382812,-9.0
110002,1,11,Rondônia,RO,1045.0,-117719.81003307365,59896.85141422227,87390.55027151108,-517462.1293435469,-344340.1194701195,-39947.149419976406,12767.351586818699,-159.0
110003,1,11,Rondônia,RO,1800.0,11995.520141601562,-4437.009887695313,-6717.149902343751,-14681.409790039062,-1967.699951171875,-2924.1500244140634,-2208.530029296877,-9.0
110004,1,11,Rondônia,RO,1178.530029296875,-39242.82833099365,1061295.4395132065,-691349.540539017,-307067.91276313737,-190336.46457696892,3313113.0207483675,-63279.9770410154,-65.0
110005,1,11,Rondônia,RO,1155.0,103363.67004394531,25018.399658203125,-33313.39031982422,-83838.8603515625,-10061.860534667969,4511.009948730469,-14397.039794921875,0.0
110006,1,11,Rondônia,RO,-1232.0,-50981.78991699219,60987.15966796875,-15274.68994140625,-15574.679809570312,5397.749755859374,9945.92041015625,19075.240295410156,9.0
```

I intend to change the `MS/Jan2020`,`MS/Fev2020`,`MS/Mar2020`,`MS/Abr2020`,`MS/Mai2020`,`MS/Jun2020`,`MS/Jul2020`,`MS/Aug2020`,`MS/Set2020` - which are values in different months - columns to lines with their correspondent value indexed to `Código do Município`.

So, it should look like this:

```
Código do Município,Código da Grande Região,Código UF,Nome da UF,Sigla da UF,MS 
110001,1,11,Rondônia,RO,-1188.0
110001,1,11,Rondônia,RO,17586.389719238505
110001,1,11,Rondônia,RO,13315.370187988505
110001,1,11,Rondônia,RO,-17071.370004883036
```

And so on.

Basically, for every Código do Município I want to put all of those values that are located on the same line but different columns so they can be on the same column but different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [df.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
# Columns that you want to save "as is"
In [44]: cols = ['Código do Município', 'Código da Grande Região', 'Código UF', 'Nome da UF', 'Sigla da UF']

In [45]: df.melt(cols)
Out[45]:
    Código do Município  Código da Grande Região  Código UF Nome da UF Sigla da UF    variable         value
0                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Jan2020 -1.188000e+03
1                110002                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Jan2020  1.045000e+03
2                110003                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Jan2020  1.800000e+03
3                110004                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Jan2020  1.178530e+03
4                110005                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Jan2020  1.155000e+03
5                110006                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Jan2020 -1.232000e+03
6                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Fev2020 -1.758639e+04
7                110002                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Fev2020 -1.177198e+05
8                110003                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Fev2020  1.199552e+04
9                110004                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Fev2020 -3.924283e+04
10               110005                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Fev2020  1.033637e+05
11               110006                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Fev2020 -5.098179e+04
12               110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Mar2020  1.331537e+04
13               110002                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Mar2020  5.989685e+04
14               110003                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Mar2020 -4.437010e+03
15               110004                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  MS/Mar2020  1.061295e+06
...
```

then, you can drop the `"variable"` column and rename the `"value"` column, and finally reorder as you want:

```
In [46]: df.melt(cols).drop(columns=['variable']).rename(columns=dict(value='MS')).sort_values(by=cols).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[46]:
    Código do Município  Código da Grande Região  Código UF Nome da UF Sigla da UF            MS
0                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO -1.188000e+03
1                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO -1.758639e+04
2                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  1.331537e+04
3                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO -1.707137e+04
4                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO -1.591753e+04
5                110001                        1         11   Rondônia          RO  1.424300e+03
...
```

Comment: that worked very well, thanks! For some reason I had the wrong idea about what the df.melt() meant. Thanks anyway.